# How can I load text files into an HTML file using a drop down menu?

Tags: javascript

I have three versions of a text, and I want to load different versions into an HTML file using a drop-down menu. Is there a way to do this using Javascript or something else?

Comment: That's called AJAX. It's a very broad subject.

Comment: But if you can provide a better description of your use case (eg. how the data can be accessed) it would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

sure.  put each text in a variable and swap out the div's .innerText property when the menu changes.  or if you dont want to include all the text in the html, you can put each text in a text file on the web server and request the contents via ajax.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't even aware there was an .innerText property. That's awesome.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not averse to using jQuery, it's pretty simple. Check out a little demo on jsFiddle. It's really basic, but it should point you in the right direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/2zGZ8/1/